# Different selenium behaviour on Python

Tags: python, selenium

Dear Python community,

I did a small scrip on Python 3 with Selenium to automatize some basic tasks                         online. It worked fine. It opened the firefox browser, logged in on a web, type text on a search field, etc. Nothing too fancy.

I am still learning and trying different things so in the meantime I installed anaconda, python 2.7, and updated python 3 form 3.4 (I think) to 3.6. I messed something up with all this.

Now my script doesn't work anymore...

First it complaint that the geckodriver was not found. I am sure I didn't installed the first time. Anyway I downloaded it and put it on a Path enviroment varible.

Script then runs but doesn't stop were it did before. It does not wait for the page to load. If I don't want it to fail I have to use the explicit/implicit wait on selenium.

I have problems as well when finding elements on the web using `browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text` that when I wrote the script worked well.

```
def download(serial,apoc_user,apoc_pass):
    shutil.rmtree(aux.download_path, ignore_errors=True)


    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', aux.absolut_path + aux.download_path)
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', aux.all_types_of_files)

    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

    browser.get("https://some.web.com")

    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
    elem.send_keys(user)
    passElem = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
    passElem.send_keys(password)
    browser.find_element_by_id('loginBtn').click()

    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('Asset')
    elem.send_keys(serial)
    elem.submit()
```

Before twinkering my code, does someone know what is going now? 
I currently have python 3.6 and selenium 3.0.0. I tried with python 3.5 and selenium 3.0.2 without success.
I code with Pycharm Community Edition running on windows 7.

Any help will be welcomed!
Thank you all.